# Websphere 7 & JSTL: Cannot get value from arrays -> Missing Resource in EL implementation: ???propertyNotReadable?

Tags: java, jsp, websphere, el

Since upgrading from WAS6.1 to WAS7.0 I'm getting an error when trying to display a value contained in an array.

Java:

```
private Date[] days = new Date[10];
public Date[] getDays() {
    return days;
}
```

JSP:

```
<td><fmt:formatDate value="${fair.days[0]}" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" /><td>
```

This causes the following error:

```
[Exception in:/tilesContent/listFairs_bodyarea.jsp] Missing Resource in EL
 implementation: ???propertyNotReadable???
```

My application works fine when deployed to a WAS6.1 server. The problem only occurs on WAS7.

I added a getFirstDay() method which returns days[0] and accessed it using ${fair.firstDay} and this works. Is there a problem accessing arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have found an partial explanation and a work-around for the problem.

I added a new indexed property to the Fair class to check that indexed
properties work ok. They do.

I added a new getter for the days array and gave it the name getXyz(). That worked ok.

I noticed that the original getter and setter were asymetrical (hysterical reasons).

```
public Date[] getDays() {                                               
    return days;                                                        
}                                                                       
public void setDay(int day, Date date) {                                
    this.days[day] = date;                                              
}
```

I know this is a bit wierd but it worked up til now. Anyway, I modified 
the methods as follows:

```
public Date[] getDays() {                                               
    return days;                                                        
}                                                                       
public void setDays(Date[] dates) {                                     
    this.days = dates;                                                  
}                                                                       
public void setDay(int day, Date date) {                                
    this.days[day] = date;                                              
}
```

The problem no longer occurs.

I have no explaination for why this fixes the problem as I think that only the getter is being used. This 'solution' is ok for me as the code looks better and it works.

(Feel free to add a comment if you know WHY this solves the problem)

Answer (score 1):

There's actually another problem: the actual exception message cannot be found in the EL implementation used. This indicates that you've another, older versioned, EL implementation in your classpath which is colliding with the one supplied by the applicationserver.

Ensure that you don't have any JAR files in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` which are specific to one server. Clean up the folder to get rid of any server-specific JAR files.

Comment: Just had a look on the server. /WEB-INF/lib is empty apart from struts.jar. That jar is placed there automatically and not explicitly by me. +1 'cos it's a useful tip.

Comment: Check other classpath locations, e.g. JRE/lib, JRE/lib/ext. This is clearly a sign of classpath pollution of different versioned classes/JARs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What should I be looking for exactly? I'm pretty sure that we're doing a clean deploy - delete server, create server, install etc.